# ArcGIS Web AppBuilder Query Widget acts strangely on Android?

Tags: android, arcgis-web-appbuilder, widget

I am viewing an ArcGIS Online Web AppBuilder app on an Android. I have a Query Widget which searches an address string to locate a parcel. When setting up the Query Widget, I selected "Ask for values." For the expression, I left the value blank and selected "Unique" so as to obtain a list of all of the unique values.

The app works well on desktop, but when viewed on both an Android and IPad, the Query has a couple of issues:

1. It is not acting responsively. The input screen hovers to the right of the device screen and is only half visible. The full screen mode does work responsively, though.
2. When I type in a character in the "specify parameters for this task" box, the first value in my list that has the character automatically prefills rather than providing me with a list of the records that match my character (as it does when viewed on a desktop). I can backspace so only that character is in the box and the list of available options appear.

Any suggestions?

Comment: when you published did you enable mobile data access?

Comment: As for your first comment about responsiveness - Web AppBuilder still needs some CSS work. Some of the themes are clearly broken. Hopefully Esri will spend some time bug fixing this before the next release (v1.3). I've had to customize the CSS myself a few times in order to make certain themes and widgets responsive for mobile.

Comment: Thanks Nick, I thought I might have to dig into the code a bit....

Comment: When I "disable predictive text" - or autocompleting of text - on my mobile device, I solved the prefill problem mentioned above. The Query Widget windows are still not positioned properly and I need to go into the code to fix that (make app more "responsive").